A more general form of the elementary Markov property
Assume $(X_n)$ is a homogeneous Markov chain in discrete time $n=0,1,...\;$ and with countable state space $I$. By definition, $(X_n)$ satisfies the elementary Markov property, that is:
$$P(X_{n+1}=j\; |\; X_n=i,X_{n-1}=k_{n-1},...,X_0=k_0)=P(X_{n+1}=j\;|\;X_n=i)$$
for all $n\geq 0$ and all $i,j,k_0,...,k_{n-1}\in I$ whenever the conditional probabilities are defined.
My question is whether $(X_n)$ automatically satisfies the following generalization of the elementary Markov property: For all $n\geq 0$, all $A\in \sigma(X_m:m\geq n+1)$ and all $i,k_0,...,k_{n-1}\in I$
$$P(A\;|\;X_n=i,X_{n-1}=k_{n-1},...,X_0=k_0)=P(A\;|\;X_n=i)\text{.}$$
My motivation for the question is that this statement seems to be true in very simple cases which can be verified by direct computations (if I didn't do anything wrong). A simple example is
$$P(X_3=j\;|\;X_1=i, X_0=k)=P(X_3=j\;|\;X_1=i).$$
I was therefore wondering how to generalize those simple type of examples and the first idea I came up with was the generalization described above.

Yes, and you can prove it using $\pi-\lambda$ theorem.

@geetha290krm, thanks for the hint. I'll have a look at this theorem!

@geetha290krm could you explain a bit more how the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem can be applied in this situation?

Let $I:=\left\{ (n_{k},i_{n_{k}}) \right\}_{k=1}^{N}$ be a finite set of pairs (index, value) such that $n_{k} > n$ for all pairs and let
$$
A_{I} := \bigcap_{(m,j)\in I} \left\{ X_{m}=j \right\}.
$$
Let $P_{1}, P_{2}$ be two probability measures on $\sigma(X_m:m\geq n+1)$ such that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P_{1}(A)&:=& P(A\;|\;X_n=i,X_{n-1}=k_{n-1},...,X_0=k_0), \\
P_{2}(A)&:=& P(A\;|\;X_n=i).
\end{eqnarray}
$$
By direct calculations we can show that $P_{1},P_{2}$ are the same on
$$
\mathcal{P} := \left\{ A_{I} \,|\, \text{ for all } I \text{ defined as above}\right\}.
$$ $\mathcal{P}$ by definition is closed under finite intersections, therefore it is a $\pi$-system. By a direct corollary from Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem those measures are the same on $\sigma(\mathcal{P}) = \sigma(X_m:m\geq n+1)$.
